# Унаследовать `onClick` от контейнера дочерним элементам

Tags: android

В программе назначен обработчик `onClick` на контейнер `RelativeLayout`. В контейнере есть `TextView` который не реагирует на назначенный обработчик. Можно конечно этот же обработчик присвоить и `TextView`, но хотелось бы реализовать все в xml, чтобы дочерние элементы унаследовали обработчик от контейнера. Вот мой xml файл:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeFotoAdd"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffaaaaaa"
android:clickable="true"
tools:context="ru.frozik6k.lohouse.FotosFragment">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFoto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_add_photo_big" />
<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/ivFoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:text="@string/fragment_fotos_add" />
```

Возможно это как-то реализовать?

обработчик:

```
    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentClickFoto(view, mFotoNumber);
        }
    }
};
```

как он устанавливается:

```
RelativeLayout relativy = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeFotoAdd);
        relativy.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
```

Comment: Можно посмотреть на сам обработчик `onClick` и как он устанавливается?

Comment: сделайте всех дочерних элементов не focusable

Comment: сделал, не помогает. Самое интересное `ImageView` срабатывает, а `TextView` не хочет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `TextView` нужно убрать свойство `inputType`